# Restore CDATA during lxml serialization

Tags: python, lxml, cdata

I know that I can preserve CDATA sections during XML parsing, using the following:

```
from lxml import etree

parser = etree.XMLParser(strip_cdata=False)
root = etree.XML('<root><![CDATA[test]]></root>', parser)
```

See [APIs specific to lxml.etree](http://lxml.de/api.html#cdata)

But, is there a simple way to "restore" CDATA section during serialization?
For example, by specifying a list of tag names…

For instance, I want to turn:

```
<CONFIG>
    <BODY>This is a &lt;message&gt;.</BODY>
</CONFIG>
```

to:

```
<CONFIG>
    <BODY><![CDATA[This is a <message>.]]></BODY>
</CONFIG>
```

Just by telling that `BODY` should contains CDATA…

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this?

```
from lxml import etree

parser = etree.XMLParser(strip_cdata=True)
root = etree.XML('<root><x><![CDATA[<test>]]></x></root>', parser)
print etree.tostring(root)

for elem in root.findall('x'):
    elem.text = etree.CDATA(elem.text)
print etree.tostring(root)
```

Produces:

```
<root><x>&lt;test&gt;</x></root>
<root><x><![CDATA[<test>]]></x></root>
```

Comment: Yes, It’s the kind of thing I want.